# Como puedo mostrar en otra parte los errores de php

Tags: php, css, scss

cuando me da un error por ejemplo:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitio\index.php on line 5`

Quisiera que aparezca en un `div` o `section` de `html`, para que no quede feo encima de todo el contenido que sale, me pueden ayudar, para poder estilisarlo con `css`.

Comment: Con estilo o sin estilo al final son **errores** y de sintaxis además,  debes solucionarlos.Si son mensajes de error programados como validación entre otros la perspectiva puede cambiar.

Comment: te refieres a los errores enviados desde backend?

Comment: no, cuando te equivocas en el body aparece como si fuera un echo, lo que quiero esque los errores aparescan en un div o section

Comment: Y por qué en vez de adornar ese error no lo corriges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiero redireccionar el "Error Handler":

```
<?php

function customError($errno, $errstr) {
// Define global variable
    global $err1;
    $err1=  "<b>Error:</b> [$errno] $errstr";
} 

//set error handler
set_error_handler("customError");

//trigger error
echo($test);

echo "111<br>";
echo "222<br>";
echo "333<br>";
echo "444<br>";

echo "<div id='err1'>
</div>";

?>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
//  Guardamos el error en el div con id err1
    document.getElementById('err1').innerHTML="<h1><?php echo $err1; ?></h1>";
}
</script>
```

el resultado será:

111

222

333

444

**Error: [8] Undefined variable: test**

Comment: No era lo que quería, pero estoy satisfecho, aun aparece los errores; pero me sirve.